# What is default storage account in HDInsight

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

For a given HDInsight cluster I have seen that there is a 'Default Storage Account' and 'Linked Storage Account'. What does it mean? What's special for some account to be a default storage account for a given HDInsight cluster? How is this different than any arbitrary storage account with respect to that cluster. Probably that whenever we try to access that storage account from that cluster it wont ask for keys?

And how is that different from 'Linked Storage Account' for a given HDInsight cluster? I have seen that there is generally one default storage account for a HDInsight cluster but several Linked storage accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default storage account is like system drive. Log files are stored in the default storage account. Each cluster must have a default storage account.  It is not supported to share a default storage account between two clusters. They are also some issues with reusing a default storage account for many times.

You can have many linked storage accounts.  People usually store business data in linked storage accounts.  In the past, you can only link a storage account during the cluster creation time.  Now, you can use Ambari to add linked storage accounts to a live Linux-based cluster.

see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

Comment: I got you on the default storage account -- As for the linked storage account, can you simply access the BLOBs in linked storage account with requiring the keys? I am guessing there has to be some benefit like this, otherwise almost any storage account, linked or not, you can anyways access by supplying keys right. Thanks

Comment: Linked means the keys are stored with the cluster. So the cluster can access the storage account, and  you don't need to worry about providing the keys.

Comment: managed hive tables will always reside in default storage? This is problem in a scenario where you are creating/deleting a cluster as and when required pointing to a common shared Hive Metastore because every time you create a cluster , existing hive managed tables will keep pointing to old path (path of the container which was default storage container during earlier cluster creation). Is there any way to specify that Hive Metastore Warehouse directory should refer to some linked storage , since this can always be kept constant irrespective of how many times we are deleting/creating cluster?